# Bind variable method to a click event

Tags: jquery

I have some trouble with jQuery, I'd like to bind an event to a div generated

```
myArray = [ {name : 'object1', clickMethod : function(){...}},
          {name : 'object2', clickMethod : function(){...}},
          {name : 'object3', clickMethod : function(){...}}
        ]
```

In my loop i'd like to do something like this :

```
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  Utils.getGeneratedHtml(myArray[i])
}

//Utils.getGeneratedHtml
Utils.getGeneratedHtml = function(element,selector) {
     var newE = $('<strong />',{id : element.name}).append(element.name);
     newE.click(function(){
        element.clickMethod()
     })

    newE.appendTo(selector);
}
```

However it looks like the method is not taken in consideration. Should I use classes instead ?

Comment: you shouldn't name your variable as `new`, it is a reserved keyword of [tag:javascript]

Comment: new is a reserved word, try renaming it to something else (e.g. newElement) and then see if it works

Comment: sorry that was for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an inline function you need to declare it before you want to use it and use var to define it. Note that "." is not allowed in variable names in javascript. Also you are not passing the selector-parameter to your getGeneratedHtml-function. See the example:

```js
var myArray = [{
  name: 'object1',
  clickMethod: function() {
    alert("clicked");
  }
}, {
  name: 'object2',
  clickMethod: function() {
    alert("clicked");
  }
}, {
  name: 'object3',
  clickMethod: function() {
    alert("clicked");
  }
}]

var getGeneratedHtml = function(element, selector) {
  var newE = $('<strong />', {
    id: element.name
  }).append(element.name);
  newE.click(function() {
    element.clickMethod()
  })

  newE.appendTo(selector);
}

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  getGeneratedHtml(myArray[i], "div")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `var new` is not valid and should throw error, because `new` is keyword.

You need to use live events `$('static-el').on('event', 'dynamic-el', function)` for your code to work.

Comment: Actually in this case he does not need on-method since he is attaching the  event manually to every generated element. This answer does not answer the ops question.